# Why Docker does not find Flask Module

Tags: python, bash, docker, flask

I've created flask app and try to dockerize it. It uses machine learning libraries, I had some problems with download it so my Dockerfile is a little bit messy, but Image was succesfully created.

```
from alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev \
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

FROM python:3.5
RUN pip3 install gensim
RUN pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH
ENV FLASK_APP /sentiment-service/__init__.py

CMD ["python","-m","flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]
```

and when i try:
docker run my_app:latest
I get

```
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named flask
```

Of course I have Flask==1.1.1 in my requirements.txt file.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are there two `FROM` lines? And why are you overwriting `requirements.txt`?

Comment: How does your `requirements.txt` look like after the `freeze`? Can you please add it.

Comment: @KlausD. the second FROM  is because I had some problems with dowloading gensim, it fixed it. I'm overwriting requirements.txt cause I had an error that this file is not exists.

Comment: @yvesonline https://files.fm/u/ds79jg27

Comment: You are copying your files and then at the FROM a new image is build without what you have copied. Use the Python image right away.

Comment: As you run `docker build`, it will print out image IDs after each step, so you can run `docker run --rm -it 0123456789ab sh` to get an interactive debugging shell on the state of the image just before the `RUN pip3 freeze` line.  What's in your image at that point?  Why?

Comment: @danny and in the same interactive shell @David Maze suggested, run `python` to check that this is alias of the right python version you want to use.

Comment: Make sure you have created the `WORKDIR /app` before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All. Finally I rebuilded my app, simplified requirements, exclude alpine and use python 3.7 in my Dockerfile.
I could run app locally, but Docker probably could not find some file from path, or get some other error from app, that is why it stopped just after starting.